# NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition ... there are no foreign keys linking these tables

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Im using sqlalchemy to design a forum style website. I started knocking out the design but everytime I try to test it with a few inserts, it dumps a brick;

```
NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child 
tables on relationship Thread.replies - there are no foreign keys linking 
these tables. Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a 
ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Here are my "models"

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, String, create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker, backref
from .database import Base # declarative base instance

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True)
    threads = relationship("Thread", backref="user")
    posts = relationship("Post", backref="user")

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "post"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    body = Column(String)
    author = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))


class Thread(Base):
    __tablename__ = "thread"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    desc = Column(String)
    replies = relationship("Post", backref="thread")
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    board_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("board.id"))

class Board(Base):
    __tablename__ = "board"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    desc = Column(String)
    threads = relationship("Thread", backref="board")
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("category.id"))

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = "category"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    desc = Column(String)
    threads = relationship("Board", backref="category")


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = session_factory()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Post` model has no `thread` reference. Add a column to `Post` referencing the `Thread` a post belongs to:

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "post"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    body = Column(String)
    author = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    thread_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thread.id'))
```

We can't use the name `thread` because that's what the `Post.replies` relationship will add to retrieved `Thread` instances.

This is a [One to Many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#one-to-many) relationship as documented in the SQLAlchemy Relationship Configuration documentation.

Answer (score 5):

You should add a field in the Post model that reads:

```
thread_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("thread.id"), nullable=True, default=None)
```

How is SQLAlchemy supposed to know how this relationship you defined supposed to link a thhread to a post? That's why you should have a foreign key from a post to its thread. You can allow it to be null, if it does not belong to a thread, it depends on your use case.

Comment: Great answer, but Im gonna give it to martijn <3

Comment: @JakobBowyer No worries! <3 :)